# Switch between Wordpress multisite language

Tags: multisite, multi-language

My current wordpress multisite main url is Chinese language http://xxxx.com, and English url is http://xxxx.com/en
How can i switch the language so that my main url language is English and Chinese language url is http://xxxx.com/cn